# How to pass data to livewire modal component?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have category component with add button as below.

```
<button wire:click.prevent="addNew" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add</button>
  .....
  .....
<x-mymodal-component :iscreate="$iscreate"/>
```

with 'addNew' method, I dispatch event to javascript listener.

```
public function addNew(){
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('show-category-modal');
}
```

In the listener event, I try to show modal that made as component.

```
  window.addEventListener('show-category-modal', event => {
    $('#category-form').modal('show');
  });
```

Below is modal component with data that need to pass into.

```
<x-mymodal-component :iscreate="$iscreate"/>
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@livewire('mymodal-component', ['iscreate'=>$iscreate])

//Receive:
 public function mount($iscreate)
  {

  }
```